# Use Assembly to create a zip for maven build and deploy it to github

Tags: java, maven, github, travis-ci

i am making the build of my java project on Travis integration server.
i already use the command on .travis.yml to create the zip for my maven build:

mvn clean package assembly:assembly

But does anyone have an idea of how can i send this zip file to my github repository too during automatic build?

Comment: Firts you should bind the assembly creation into your build life cycle and don't call maven-assembly-plugin separately. So the result should be juse call `mvn clean package`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do whatever you want after build. Simply put it in "after_script" tag in .travis.yml.

Comment: And what should i put on .travis.yml to get what i want?

Comment: You can create a script to upload the file to github and call them from .travis.yml

Comment: and what do i put on script? I can´t seem to find any tutorial of building a script on Travis-ci to upload a file to my github repository